# Find the index of the n-least values in a array without sorting

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array:

```
{7, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 8, 2}
```

and a empty n-size array. Now I want to find the index of the n-least values in that given array without sorting and write them to the empty array. For example n = 3:

```
{1, 8, 2}
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: should be `{1, 3, 2}`, right?

Comment: Start with first value in array. Is there room in the `n-least` array? Then add the index to the `n-least` array. When the `n-least` array is full: Compare the values from the array and the value of the index in the `n-least` array. If the value is less then add that index to that position in the `n-least` array and shift the rest. If it's not less then compare the next value from the `n-least` array and so forth. This is probably not optimal but atleast it's not of `O(n^2)` complexity that a naive solution would yield.

Comment: No, because the second array contains the index not the value of the given array. `{1, 2, 8}` is the unordered sequence.

Comment: can you not modify the array at all?

Comment: No, but if it were possible I would sort the array and take the first n values.

Comment: *Now I want to find the index of the n-least values in that given array without sorting* -- Use an index array.  Sort that index array instead of the original array, using the original array as a guide in how to sort the index array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not restricted in sorting *other* arrays, then create an array of indices and sort the array of indices in accordance with the original array.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{

    int n = 3;

    // test data
    std::vector<int> test = { 7, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 8, 2 };

    // index array
    std::vector<int> index(test.size());

    // set the index array to 0, 1, 2, … n-1
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    // sort the index array
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&](int n1, int n2) { return test[n1] < test[n2]; });

    // output results -- note we are printing the index array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << index[i] << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
8 
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with first value in array.

Compare the values from the array and the value of the index in the `n-least` array. (If empty then just add it).

If the value is less, then shift the array from that position and add the index to that position in the `n-least` array.

If it's not less then compare the next value from the `n-least` array and so forth.

This is probably not optimal but atleast it's not of O(n^2) complexity that a naive solution would yield.

I'll write this in pseudo code:

```
n = 3
arr = [7, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 8, 2]
narr = []

for i as 0 to sizeof(arr) - 1
  for j as 0 to n - 1
    if narr[j] is undefined or arr[i] < arr[narr[j]]
      narr.shiftRight(j, 1)
      narr[j] = i;
      break
    endif
  endfor
endfor
```